# Which Linux is best for beginners

Tags: application-development, web-development

I am totally new to Linux i want to try Linux since I heard it is best for web and app development.but I am not sure to choose which Linux is best like Ubuntu,mint and so... So can anyone tell which will be good for new comers .is Ubuntu will be good? If so which version should I choose stable or new

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please take a moment to read the [tour]. After reading this, it will be clear to you that this type of question is not well suited, because it's asking for opinions more than facts. And also, since this is Ask Ubuntu (and only Ubuntu is on-topic), we can only recommend you try Ubuntu. That being said, Ubuntu should be a good start for beginners. 

Comment: In addition to what's already been said, I would recommend Ubuntu MATE, which is an official flavor of Ubuntu. You can download and create live USB to try out before installing: https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/

Comment: The only OS on-topic on this site is Ubuntu, so why ask such a question here? (*particularly since you've not presented any problem that needs to be solved thus the question itself is off-topic as its seeking off-topic opinions better suited to forums & this is a Q&A site*). Ubuntu exists in many [*flavors*](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours); I'm using a *flavor* right now but the system itself I consider a Ubuntu one; but when it comes to *flavors* its somewhat personal preferences & if want to keep your machine fast matching DE with your wanted apps where you gave no details anyway.

Comment: Only you can decide what is best for you. Try several. They are free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu is the best because:

1. Ubuntu has great documentation and community support.
2. Ubuntu forums and Ask Ubuntu provide appreciable quality support in almost all aspects of Ubuntu.
3. You should easily find answers to common issues and even if you notice something new, the community will help you out with troubleshooting

   [Best Linux Distributions That are Most Suitable for Beginners](https://itsfoss.com/best-linux-beginners/)